# Save data to local storage and have it persist across pages using jQuery

Tags: jquery, local-storage

The problem I'm having is that the element with class `order-total` only exists on one page. When I am on that page it works and displays the text to the the `.col-6` in the header. Local storage shows that it is saving the key/value pair.

The header is reused on every page and when I go to another page that does not have the element with class `order-total` I don't see the value in the header. I only see the key `order total` in localStorage and the value is blank.

How can I get the value to persist on the other pages once the value is saved?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var total = $(".order-total").text();
  localStorage.setItem("order total", total);
  console.log(total);

  var finalTotal = localStorage.getItem("order total");
  $(".col-6").append(finalTotal);
});
```

Comment: `localStorage` is common for all page.  what u want exact result in you Q?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because if the `.order-total` element doesn't exist on the page `text()` will return an empty string. You then overwrite the `order total` in localStorage with that empty value.

To fix this check that the element exists in the page before setting the localStorage value. I would also suggest removing the whitespace in the localStorage key. Try this:

```js
var $total = $(".order-total");
if ($total.length)
  localStorage.setItem("ordertotal", $total.text());

var finalTotal = localStorage.getItem("ordertotal");
$(".col-6").append(finalTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're replacing the local storage with a blank value on the new page.

You need to check that the `.order-total` element exists before saving its value.

```
if ($(".order-total").length > 0) {
    var total = $(".order-total").text();
    localStorage.setItem("order total", total);
    console.log(total);
}

var finalTotal = localStorage.getItem("order total");
$(".col-6").append(finalTotal);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but only when I replaced the 0 with an empty string - " "

Comment: `length` is a number, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
//var $total = $(".order-total");
var total = 525;
localStorage.setItem("order_total", total);
var get = localStorage.getItem("order_total");
if(get!="" && get!=null){
    console.log(get);
    //$(".col-6").append(finalTotal);
}
localStorage.removeItem("order_total");
var get = localStorage.getItem("order_total");
if(get!="" && get!=null){
    console.log(get);
    //$(".col-6").append(finalTotal);
}else{
    console.log("No Data");
}
```

`Test chrome console`